# Nvidia - 2 cards, 4 monitors

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

System is Windows XP Professional 32 bit and I have 2x Leadtek GTX550 Ti graphics cards to replace broken parts and I need to urgently setup a 4 monitor layout (2x2) for critical mission management operations which can only be delayed for another 10 hours.

The vendor assured me that these cards can do what I need them to do on my platform but the maximum the NVIDIA Control Panel supports is DualView, I cannot find any options to achieve a 4 monitor layout. Drivers are installed correctly and I've tried both new (296?), old, and ones on the disc (275?). The monitors unfortunately use DVI-to-VGA adapters.

Unfortunately, these are all the parts I have and it is impossible to source others in time. The software doesn't operate on a dual monitor setup. Is this setup possible given my hardware? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Superuser.com is wonderful but any business that relies on SU for urgent mission-critical support probably needs a refocusing of priorities and a re-think of business-continuity planning. The vendor should be helping more, are they not answering this Q? Escalate!

Comment: They're useless, suffice to say, we won't be using them any more. With a 1000% markup on products compared to normal consumer retail I expect better service. Either way, I'm stuck with this problem with no solution and no other recourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We hooked up a bunch of personal laptops and used virtual display adapter software to use them as additional monitors. We actually contacted nVidia who told us that the modern Geforce range isn't capable of that setup.

One good thing did come out of it, it forced those in charge to force our software vendor to provide preliminary support for Windows 7 which eliminates a lot of our problems such as this.

Answer (score 0):

If your 560 card have two DVI output (not DVI-VGA), you can use **only one DVI-monitor** (I had flamewar here with some <strike>idiots</strike>*victims of a consumer society* some time ago, which appealed to docs and specs, while I **had and have two 560 cards in battle**) and use second monitor with HDMI-interface.

Driver replacement change nothing.

Sad, but true... I know, DVI-VGA 560 cards exist on market

Comment: We could use both DVI outputs on the primary card and achieve DualView, it's just the NVIDIA Control Panel wouldn't even see the outputs of the other card. We could unplug the monitors from the primary card and restart and the system would make the secondary card the primary, both cards were picked up in Device Manager too with working drivers.